# Page Not Found on URL rewrite with multiple Parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have been rewriting the URL with multiple parameters but it throws me Error 404. Here is what i used

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^city/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ city.php?city=$1 [NC,L] -- This one Works fine
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ blog.php?city=$1&cat=$2 [NC,L] -- This one is not
```

Second RewriteRule is not working. I have tried to change to QSA too but it didn't work.

Comment: `$` = ends of string, so it should not be in the middle of the rule

Comment: you mean something like this 
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ blog.php?city=$1&cat=$2 [NC,L]
if yes , it didnt still work.

Comment: Try disabling MultiViews, it is often responsible for such conflicts when you try to rewrite from a URL path that “overlaps” with an existing file name (`blog/` vs. `blog.php`) If that doesn’t help, then please give an example of the URL you are trying to access in your browser.

Comment: @misorude -  added "Options -MultiViews" at the top of the .htaccess file but still didn't work. URL http://example.com/demo_2/blog.php?city=Seattle&cat=latest" if try this then it's working which is obvious but when try this http://example.com/demo_2/blog/Seattle/latest/ .. it isn't

Comment: Do you have this .htaccess file located inside the `demo_2` folder? If you have it on the root level, then `^blog` of course won’t match, so in that case you would have to add the path prefix in that regular expression as well.

Comment: @misorude .. yes, .htaccess file is inside demo_2 folder.Right now i am testing it on my server and later on will be updated to some other URL. Then i will be shifting .htaccess file to root folder but how can I add a path? can you help me out with the code?

Comment: Well if it is inside the folder, then you don’t need to add the path in the pattern. But it could be that you need to specify a [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) in this situation. I that doesn’t help either, then enable rewrite logging, so that you can see what is going on for every step of the process.

Comment: @misorude  Thanks for the help. I checked the log file and figured that '$' weren't required in RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) blog.php?city=$1&cat=$2 [NC,L] . It Worked !!!

Comment: `$` matches the end of the subject string, so `$/` makes no sense, there can’t be a slash “after the end”.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) blog.php?city=$1&cat=$2 [NC,L] -- Removed '$' and It worked.
```